# React typescript (2312,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react project I use typescript with, but recently, after I did a `yarn upgrade` it stopped working, with this error: `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
(2312,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.`

My tsconfig.json looks like this: https://hastebin.com/govenilayi.json
My pkg.json looks like this: https://hastebin.com/ixezizifec.json

When I run `yarn why react` and `yarn why react-dom`, it comes up with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPeEt.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/lutdp.png

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the other definition of `LibraryManagedAttributes`?  (There should be several errors identifying the locations of the duplicate definitions, or if there aren't, navigate to the definition of `LibraryManagedAttributes` in `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts` and "find all references".)

Comment: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/11697

Comment: In found a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399839/typescript-duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes