# Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the same issue as in:

[React typescript (2312,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339225/react-typescript-2312-14-duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes)

and

[TypeScript error: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323056/typescript-error-duplicate-identifier-librarymanagedattributes)

But I just can't find any solution.

I already upgraded to the latest node/npm/yarn/typescript versions. Also tried downgrading. Nothing helps.

```
yarn build --verbose
yarn run v1.9.4
$ react-scripts-ts build --verbose
Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
ts-loader: Using typescript@3.0.3 and C:\dev\project\frontend\tsconfig.prod.json
Warning: member-ordering - Bad member kind: public-before-private
Failed to compile.

C:/dev/project/frontend/node_modules/@types/prop-types/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
(2312,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

`--verbose` somehow doesn't give me more information.

As I can see `LibraryManagedAttributes` is defined in:

- `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`
- `node_modules/@types/prop-types/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`
- `node_modules/@types/react-overlays/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`
- ....

**Where is this coming from? How can I avoid that?**

I want to find out where this error is coming from so that I can report it to the right entity but I don't know where to start.

**What else can I try?**

Comment: Yarn shouldn't be installing multiple copies of `@types/react` like that.  Try deleting your `yarn.lock` file and running `yarn install` again.  If that doesn't help, try removing all dependencies from `package.json` except `@types/react`, `@types/prop-types`, and `@types/react-overlays` and see if you still get the problem.  If so, add your `package.json` and `yarn.lock` (it should be no more than ~40 lines) to the question so we can see why yarn is doing what it is doing.

Comment: Deleting the yarn.lock file actually helped. I'm still worried this just repeats at some day. I'm not sure how this came to be in the first place. It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/28881

Comment: If anyone is facing an issue because of @types/react-dom internal dependency and @types/react clashing, you can try this answer, which basically uninstalled and reinstalled them both in a single go. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239498/4353782

Answer (score 177):

This seems te happen because Yarn resolves multiple versions of a package; `@types/react` in this particular case. Yarn resolves `@types/react` from your package.json and as a dependency of `@types/react-dom`.

Take the following snippet from my **package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^15.0.16",
  "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.23"
  ...
}
```

The **yarn.lock** that is created after you run `yarn install` contains something similar to this:

```
"@types/react-dom@^0.14.23":
  version "0.14.23"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-dom/-/react-dom-0.14.23.tgz#cecfcfad754b4c2765fe5d29b81b301889ad6c2e"
  dependencies:
    "@types/react" "*"

"@types/react@*":
  version "16.4.14"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-16.4.14.tgz#47c604c8e46ed674bbdf4aabf82b34b9041c6a04"
  dependencies:
    "@types/prop-types" "*"
    csstype "^2.2.0"

"@types/react@^15.0.16":
  version "15.6.19"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-15.6.19.tgz#a5de18afe65b0f29767328836b48c498a5d3a91b"
```

Notice that `@types/react-dom` depends on any version of `@types/react` as indicated by `"*"`. Yarn resolves two versions of `@types/react`: `"16.4.14"` and `"15.6.19"`. This results in the type conflicts you mentioned.

The solution is to add a [resolutions field](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to your **package.json** to tell Yarn to resolve a specific version of `@types/react`. Take the following sample:

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^15.0.16"
}
```

Run `yarn install` again. Notice the change in the **yarn.lock** file:

```
"@types/react-dom@^0.14.23":
  version "0.14.23"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-dom/-/react-dom-0.14.23.tgz#cecfcfad754b4c2765fe5d29b81b301889ad6c2e"
  dependencies:
    "@types/react" "*"

"@types/react@*", "@types/react@^15.0.16":
  version "15.6.19"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-15.6.19.tgz#a5de18afe65b0f29767328836b48c498a5d3a91b"
```

Yarn now resolves the same version `"15.6.19"` for both `"@types/react@*"` and `"@types/react@^15.0.16"` dependencies.

I would like to know myself why this is needed. I would expect Yarn to understand it can resolve dependency `"@types/react" "*"` with `"@types/react@^15.0.16"` instead of resolving it with the latest version of `@types/react`.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this answer brought me closer to the solution. However, I also had to delete the `node_modules` folder before `yarn install`, since otherwise `yarn install` would not act sufficiently on the changed `package.json`. (I edited the answer accordingly to keep other readers from running into that problem, but strangely that got peer-rejected.)

Comment: Once the lockfile has been updated is it safe to remove the `resolutions` field?

Comment: Yes, it's safe to remove the resolutions config once the new lock file has been created.

Comment: @sander schutten Thanks, I have created a bug report for React team https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20005

Comment: You can use `yarn why @types/react` to get additional information of where these differing versions are coming from. In my case I had a 17.x and 16.x version, the latter of which came from a dependency I didn't actually use so I could just remove it.

Answer (score 49):

This seems to be a typescript issue.

My current workaround is adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to `tsconfig.json`.

I want to stress that that is only a workaround and not a fix to the problem it self.

Comment: Has this been resolved? I just tried to create and application and received this error.

Comment: Note that adding `"skipLibCheck": true` to tsconfig is a potentially destructive action on the type-safety of your codebase, and is very hard to undo.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Saved my day, enabling skipLibCheck works for me , For me it was not working only in my local so enabling skipLibCheck flag should fine for me

Answer (score 29):

I got the same error. I managed to fixed it by removing my '@types/react' and then installing them again.

```
yarn remove @types/react
yarn add --dev @types/react
```

Answer (score 24):

For me I had react types duplicated in `react-redux`, `react`, and `react-intl` when I upgraded `react-intl`. The least intrusive fix that's worked for me so far is to run this:

`npx yarn-deduplicate --packages @types/react yarn.lock`

If the resulting diff of the lockfile looks correct, go ahead and delete `node_modules`, then `yarn` to get fresh packages off the deduplicated lockfile.

Comment: Thanks for this. This solved the issue right away. Should be marked as the answer

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks much!

Answer (score 10):

In my case the error showed up when the version numbers of `@types/react` (v17.0.3) and `@types/react-dom` (v17.0.2) have not been in sync.

To solve the issue, I removed `@types/react` because it gets hoisted from `@types/react-dom`. You can verify that by executing `yarn why @types/react`.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to fix this for me was to delete my node_modules directory and yarn.lock/package-lock files and then do a yarn install to reinstall all the node modules.

Answer (score 5):

Related to the question, running `npm list @types/react` from the directory of your package.json should list duplicate type definitions found in your project.

Answer (score 5):

In our case, we fixed it by

1. Moving all `@types/*` packages to `devDependencies`
2. `rm -rf yarn.lock` and `rm -rf node_modules`
3. Run `yarn install` again

Comment: in my case, I had to remove the @types/* entirely for react.

Answer (score 4):

Using [yarn-deduplicate](https://github.com/atlassian/yarn-deduplicate) fixed the issue for me.

Steps:

1. Optional install `yarn-deduplicate` package or use `npx` in step two

```
npm install -g yarn-deduplicate
```

or

```
yarn global add yarn-deduplicate
```

2. Run `yarn-deduplicate`

```
yarn-deduplicate yarn.lock --packages @types/react yarn.lock
```

or

```
npx yarn-deduplicate --packages @types/react yarn.lock
```

3. Remove `node_modules` folder

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

4. Reinstall dependencies

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue after `yarn upgrade @types/react-router-dom`. `git diff` shows multiple versions of `@types/react` resolved. In my case, `yarn upgrade @types/react` resolves the issue. Removing `yarn.lock` should help.

It seems a fresh (without `yarn.lock`) install would resolve packages to a consistent state, but a partial upgrade would not resolve the dependencies globally. Thus manual tweaks may be necessary to upgrade all involved packages.

Comment: removing `yarn.lock` was the key. Deleting only `node_modules` and installing did not help.

Comment: `yarn upgrade @types/react` resolved the issue for me. I did not need to nuke the `yarn.lock` file

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was deleting `react` and `@types/react` from `package.json`, then in zsh:

```
rm -rf node_modules/**/react
npm i react @types/react
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:/Users/japa/source/repos/ReactTestApp/TemplateExample/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
TypeScript error in C:/Users/japa/source/repos/ReactTestApp/TemplateExample/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts(2835,14):
Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.  TS2300
```

In my case I needed to solve the problem manually (using principle described in [TS2300](https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/)). The problem arose once I added ReactKendo to my project.

1. Went to `ClientApp` directory in my project `ClientApp\node_modules\@types`
2. Backed up the `react` directory and then deleted it
3. Clean + Build + Run project and no more above error occures
4. I recovered the `react` folder after the bug disappeared and error seems to be gone forever, so it seems to me like typical magic bug somewhere in the universe :-)

I did not need to change anything else in config files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `npm` instead of `yarn` and try to fix your `@types/react` dependency problems by adding the following to your `package.json` :

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "x.x.x"
}
```

You might still end up with the same error. With `npm`, you should be using `overrides` instead :

```
"overrides": {
  "@types/react": "x.x.x"
}
```

This might help someone trying to fix their issue with the recommendations of this stream while working with `npm` instead of `yarn`. Note that you will still need to delete your `node_modules` and your `package-lock.json` before running `npm install` for the changes to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the error indicate that 'LibraryManagedAttributes' is declared in 2 different locations. Follow the paths, I realized that an installed module also has a package.json file which also add "@types/react" as dep, and its version is not the same as the one in the root package.json file. I changed these two to the same version and the problem was solved.

Comment: This is an old answer, but given it ranks highest for me under "active" I feel it deserves the note: you shouldn't ever modify the package.json file of a dependency. As soon as you reinstall node modules, or another dev builds from the source, your changes will not propagate and you will have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a conflicting version request for react in another module I used. Fixing that and re-installing with yarn didn't help me either.

Using NPM instead of Yarn however solved it for me.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it caused by only referenced `@types/react-redux`. Fixed by `npm i --save-dev @types/react`, and so the `package.json` looks like this:

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7"
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while working with linked dependencies. My linked package lives in a lerna repo, and it had `@types/react` as a devDependency. I added `@types/react` as a peerDependency, switched my workflow to [yalc](https://github.com/whitecolor/yalc), and was able to continue.